# Unresolve Reference: Try

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I have installed Libraries arrows core but am getting this unresolved reference error message while importing the arrow core. I have tried clearing caches and building rebuilding.
****I am Using IntelliJ Idea IDE****

Below is my code snippets

```
import arrow.core.Try //
```

I cant figure out where the Unresolved reference is occurring.

Comment: You probably forgot to also add the binaries for this external code to your project as dependency. (Download & add the jar to your build path, or use Maven or Gradle)

Comment: Build.config xx

Comment: thank you for reminding new version arrow-core version made changes. i loaded the older version and it worked.!